# Calculate width by the sum of all childs

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I would like to calculate the width of a parent element (#projects) by the sum of all child elements (.project). I tried jQuery but it doesn't work and - maybe there's someone who can help me out?

Cheers

```
var reset = 0;
var width = $(".project").each(function() { reset += $(this).width(); });
$(window).on( "resize", function () {
    $("#projects").css("width", width);
}).resize();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `css("width", reset)`?

Comment: Thereby I would apply zero (reset = 0) to the element. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Why would you use a continous event like `resize` to insert the same static value every time? Are you sure you shouldn't get the widths inside the resize handler !

Comment: @didi - nope, your `width` variable is a jQuery collection of elements, not a number

Comment: Yes, you are wrong, reset is not zero, try using `console.log(reset)` to see.

Comment: Alright. My goal is to sum all child elements (.project) and set that result as width for the parent element (#projects). Once the window is resized, there should be a new calculation.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/gte9cftv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    var width = 0;
    $('.project').each(function() {
        width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
    });
    $('#projects').css('width', width);
}).resize();
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var projects = $("#projects"),
    project = projects.find(".project"), // just caching the dom for performance
    setWidth = function() { // you want is as a function
        var totalWidth = 0,

        project.each(function() {
            totalWidth += $(this).width();
        });

        projects.width(totalWidth);
    };

$(window).on("resize", setWidth).resize(); // handler
```